# simple api with basic auth

Tags: node.js, api, axios

I have:

```
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios');

exports.getEvents = async (req, res) => {

    const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });

    try {
      await axios.get('http://localhost/api/events',
      { 
        httpsAgent,
        auth: {
          username: "senstar",
          password: "senstar"
        }
      }).then(resp => {
        res.json(resp.data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

this's a simple api, I test `http://localhost/api/events'` on postman, using `Authorization: Basic Auth`  and work it. So I implement the function `getEvents`  to get the results on node js, but this's not working, why? what's wrong? with basic auth?

Comment: You're trying to send the auth data with `GET`, are you sure this is the right behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios');
const base64 = require('base-64');

exports.getEvents = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await axios.get('https://127.0.0.1/api/events',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode("senstar" + ":" + "senstar")
                }
            }).then(resp => {
                res.json(resp.data);
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue,

Comment: @jhonestrada It means not Authorization issue. Can you success by Postman?

Comment: yes! in postman ir work

Comment: @jhonestrada, Can you share Postman's screen for `Authorization` and `Headers` section with URL and response Body?

Comment: yes, so let me update the question and I'll add some image

Comment: @jhonestrada, Thanks, I updated my try code too. That is as same as Postman, Can you try that?

Comment: I had this issue ```AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400```

Comment: No idea if you use same URL 'http://127.0.0.1/api/events', it wont be 400 error.

Comment: yes I'm using the same URL ```http://127.0.0.1/api/events```, currently I'm running local host port 4222, could this be a problem?

Comment: It's a problem, should be use `http://127.0.0.1:4222/api/events`

Comment: the issue is ```'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',``` I added on postman and give me the same error ```Bad Request HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed. ```

Comment: Without your local events server, I can't figure out.

Comment: Can you share your local event server source code?

Comment: Bro! I found the solution, I added ```htpps``` instead ```http```, and remove ```'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',``` and worked it.... please remove ```'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',``` of your answer and I'll mark it as correct answer please

Comment: @jhonestrada, Good News!, I updated it.

Comment: @jhonestrada, Thanks for your cooperation. You are first person to active to find an  answer.